# C crypto program with stdin, stdout, stderr and error message

Tags: c, stdout, stdin, stderr

I am working on what should be a simple c program that takes two args a char either e or d and a key.  If e it will encrypt and if d decrypt using the key in both cases. It reads in from stdin and outputs to either stdout or stderr if there is an error.  I am getting the warning message

*cypher.c:30:4: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fputc’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default] 
/usr/include/stdio.h:579:12: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘char

The program compiles and encodes, but the decode does not appear to work also it does not throw an error if it is passed a char other then d or e as it should.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*has been edited to address some of the issues such as, last fputc() is now fputs(), the i++ was added back into last loop, and the if(ende = e) replaced with if(ende == "e").  The error code is no longer an issue, but program functionality appear to be still.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main(char ende, char key[150]){

  int e; 
  int  i=0;      
  int c=fgetc(stdin);
  int n=strlen(key);

   if(ende == "e"){
       while(c != EOF){
          c= fgetc(stdin);
          e=(c - 32 + key[i % n]) % 95 + 32;
          fputc( e, stdout);
          i++;
       }
    }
   else if (ende == "d"){
       while(e != EOF){
         e= fgetc(stdin);
         c=(e - 32 - key[i % n] + 3 *95) %95 + 32;
         fputc( c, stdout);
         i++
       }
    }
 else{
   fputs("you broke it",stderr);
   exit (1);
     }
   exit (0);
}
```

Comment: Your last fputc doesn't follow the rule. fputc should only input a single character. instead use fputs.

Comment: Read about passing parameters to your program

Comment: ok, well i found my first error at some point i accidentaly deleted the i++ from the decode block.

Comment: any chance you know of a useful article for passing parameters in c?

Answer (score 2):

Something wrong with the `if (ende = e)`, maybe is `if (ende == e)` and `else if (ende  == d)`

Answer (score 1):

```
fputc("you broke it",stderr);
```

`fputc()` takes an `int` as first argument, it should be:

```
fprintf(stderr, "you broke it");
```

Also your `main()` is not standard:

```
main(char ende, char key[150])
```

The standard `main` should be `int main(int argc, char* argv[]`, you may use different names other than `argc` and `argv`, but the type still mismatches.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int e, c, n, i;
    char *key, *ende;

    i = 0;
    ende = argv[1];
    key = argv[2];
    n = strlen(key);
    c = fgetc(stdin);

    if (strcmp(ende, "e") == 0) {
        while(c != EOF){
            e=(c - 32 + key[i % n]) % 95 + 32;
            fputc( e, stdout);
            i++;
            c= fgetc(stdin);
        }
    }
    else if (strcmp(ende, "d") == 0) {
        while(c != EOF){
            e=(c - 32 - key[i % n] + 3 *95) %95 + 32;
            fputc( e, stdout);
            i++;
            c= fgetc(stdin);
        }
    }
    else{
        fputs("you broke it",stderr);
        exit (1);
    }
    exit (0);
}
```